# OpenMP: Include atomic section into parrallel region declaration

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a parallel region where I monitor the progress. This means I use the the variable `iteration` to calculate the current state of the loop (percentage: 0 - 100 until loop is finished).

For this I increment with an `atomic` operation. Is there a way to make the code shorter, maybe by including `iteration++` into the `#pragma omp parallel for`  clause?

```
  int iteration = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for 
  for (int64_t ip = 0; ip < num_voxels; ip++)
  {
    // calc stuff
#pragma omp atomic
    iteration++;
    // output stuff
    // if thread == 0:
    // Progress(iteration / num_voxels * 100);
  }
```

Comment: You could make it shorter, and quicker, by dropping the `atomic` directive and the `iteration` counter too.  Have each thread report it's own progress.

Comment: You should state the intend of using the `iteration` variable rather than the loop counter `ip`, this would make a solution more directed.

Comment: i updated the question. The intention is that I calculate a percentual porgress until loop is finished.

Comment: Do not mix `int` and `int64_t`. `int` can overflow in your code, which is _undefined behavior_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to increment `iteration` elsewhere than inside the loop body. For instance, this is not allowed:

```
std::atomic<int> iteration{0};
#pragma omp parallel for 
for (int64_t ip = 0; ip < num_voxels; ip++, iteration++) { ...
```

since OpenMP requires so-called *Canonical Loop Form* where the increment expression may not update multiple variables (see Section 2.6 of OpenMP 4.5 Spcification).

---

Also I would strongly advise against incrementing `iteration` within each loop, since it would be very inefficient (atomic memory operations = memory fences and cache contention).

I would prefer, e.g.:

```
int64_t iteration = 0;
int64_t local_iteration = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(local_iteration) 
for (int64_t ip = 0; ip < num_voxels; ip++) {
{
   ... // calc stuff      
   if (++local_iteration % 1024 == 0) { // modulo using bitwise AND
     #pragma omp atomic
     iteration += 1024;
   }
   // output stuff
   // if thread == 0:
   // Progress(iteration / num_voxels * 100);
}
```

---

And, output only if progress in percents changes. This might be also tricky, since you need to read `iteration` atomically and you likely don't want to do that in each iteration. A possible solution, which also saves a lot of cycles regarding "expensive" integer division:

```
int64_t iteration = 0;
int64_t local_iteration = 0;
int64_t last_progress = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(local_iteration) 
for (int64_t ip = 0; ip < num_voxels; ip++) {
{
   ... // calc stuff      
   if (++local_iteration % 1024 == 0) { // modulo using bitwise AND
      #pragma omp atomic
      iteration += 1024;

      // output stuff:
      if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0) {
         int64_t progress;
         #pragma omp atomic read
         progress = iteration;
         progress = progress / num_voxels * 100;
         if (progress != last_prgoress) {
            Progress(progress);
            last_progress = progress;
         }
      }
   }
}
```